# wxPython, Threads, and PostEvent between modules

Tags: python, user-interface, events, multithreading, wxpython

I'm relatively new to wxPython (but not Python itself), so forgive me if I've missed something here.

I'm writing a GUI application, which at a very basic level consists of "Start" and "Stop" buttons that start and stop a thread. This thread is an infinite loop, which only ends when the thread is stopped. The loop generates messages, which at the moment are just output using `print`.

The GUI class and the infinite loop (using `threading.Thread` as a subclass) are held in separate files. What is the best way to get the thread to push an update to something like a `TextCtrl` in the GUI? I've been playing around with `PostEvent` and `Queue`, but without much luck.

Here's some bare bones code, with portions removed to keep it concise:

**main_frame.py**

```
import wx
from loop import Loop

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
  def __init__(self, parent, title):
    # Initialise and show GUI
    # Add two buttons, btnStart and btnStop
    # Bind the two buttons to the following two methods
    self.threads = []
  def onStart(self):
    x = Loop()
    x.start()
    self.threads.append(x)
  def onStop(self):
    for t in self.threads:
      t.stop()
```

**loop.py**

```
class Loop(threading.Thread):
  def __init__(self):
    self._stop = threading.Event()
  def run(self):
    while not self._stop.isSet():
      print datetime.date.today()
  def stop(self):
    self._stop.set()
```

I did, at one point, have it working by having the classes in the same file by using `wx.lib.newevent.NewEvent()` along [these lines](http://wiki.wxpython.org/index.cgi/AsynchronousSockets). If anyone could point me in the right direction, that'd be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to use [wx.CallAfter](http://wiki.wxpython.org/CallAfter)

```
wx.CallAfter(text_control.SetValue, "some_text")
```

You can call `CallAfter` from any thread and the function that you pass it to be called will be called from the main thread.

Comment: Thank you. I'm assuming that my thread will need to be passed a window (ie. `self` in `MainFrame`) so that I can call `wx.CallAfter(self.window.text_control.SetValue.SetValue, "some_text")` in the `Loop` class?

Comment: @sam Yes, you will need access to controls you wish to modify. One way to accomplish this (as good as any other) is to pass the window to the thread.